# Matching Regex in Python from Excelfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, excel

Im using Regex to match the following excel file and Im struggling with how I can 
seperate each row by

Timestamp `[0:00:48]`, 
ID `20052A` 
and the content `content (more content)`

This is the excel row (one of many, so the ID can vary from row to row and the timestamp as well as the content too)

`[0:00:48] 20052A: content (more content)`

I get an Error code

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group`

for matching my ID where I have

`(r"^(.+:)(.+)|(r(\w+)?\s*\[(.*)\]\s*(\w+))", c)`

Keep in mind that from time to time the ID looks something like this

`[0:00:33] 30091aA: (content)`

My whole skript is (cancel out the connection to database)

````
import os
import re
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy


def insert_or_update(engine, pd_table, table_name):
    inserts = 0
    updates = 0
    for i in range(len(pd_table)):
        vals_with_quotes = ["'" + str(x) + "'" for x in pd_table.loc[i, :].values]
        # print(vals_with_quotes)
        update_pairs = [str(c) + " = '" + str(v) + "'" for c, v in zip(pd_table.columns, pd_table.loc[i, :])]
        query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({', '.join(list(pd_table.columns.values))}) " \
                f"VALUES ({', '.join(vals_with_quotes)}) " \
                f"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {', '.join(update_pairs)}"
        print(query)
        result = engine.execute(query)
        if result.lastrowid == 0:
            updates += 1
        else:
            inserts += 1
    print(f"Inserted {inserts} rows and updated {updates} rows.")


schema = '---'
alchemy_connect = "---"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(alchemy_connect)  # connect to server
engine.execute(f"USE {schema}")  # select new db
# engine.execute("SET NAMES UTF8MB4;")

query = "SELECT * FROM .... where ...=..."
pm = pd.read_sql(query, engine)

rootpath = "path/"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootpath):
    for file in files:
        print(root, dirs, files, file)
        d = pd.read_excel(root + file, header=None)
        d.drop(columns=[0], inplace=True)
        d.rename(columns={1: "content"}, inplace=True)

        participants = []

        for ix, row in d.iterrows():
            c = row["content"]

            match = re.search(r"^(.+:)(.+)|(r(\w+)?\s*\[(.*)\]\s*(\w+))", c)
            prefix = match.group(1)
            only_content = match.group(2)

            try:
                timestamp = re.search(r"\[(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})\]", prefix).group(1)
            except:
                timestamp = "-99"
            # print(timestamp)

            if re.search(r"\s(Versuchsleiter|ersuchsleiter|Versuchsleit|Versuch):", prefix):
                id_code = "Versuchsleiter"
            else:
                starting_digits = re.search(r"^(\d+)", prefix)
                id_code = re.search(r"(\d{2,4}.{1,3}):", prefix).group(1)
                if hasattr(starting_digits, 'group'):
                    id_code = starting_digits.group(1) + id_code  #

            # get pid
            participant = pm.loc[pm["id_code"] == id_code, "pid"]
            try:
                pid = participant.values[0]
            except:
                pid = "Versuchsleiter"

            # print(ix, pid, id_code, only_content, timestamp)
            if pid and pid not in participants and pid != "Versuchsleiter":
                participants.append(pid)
            d.loc[ix, "pid"] = pid
            d.loc[ix, "timestamp"] = timestamp
            d.loc[ix, "content"] = only_content.strip()
            d.loc[ix, "is_participant"] = 0 if pid == "Versuchsleiter" else 1

        d = d[["pid", "is_participant", "content", "timestamp"]]
        d.loc[(d['pid'] == "Versuchsleiter"), "pid"] = participants[0]
        d.loc[(d['pid'] == None), "pid"] = participants[0]
        insert_or_update(engine, d, "table of sql")```


I need "Versuchsleiter" since some of the ID's are "Versuchsleiter"

Thank you!
````

Comment: Try `^\[(?P<timestamp>[^][]*)]\s*(?P<ID>\w+):\s*(?P<content>.*)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zGAg3d/2)

Comment: I just want the ID part to be matched and the ID can vary from row to row, so I cant just copy the ID code

Comment: Try `(?<=:\d{2}]\s)\w+(?=:)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bz9iXq/2). What is your code? Please share. It might be probably OK to use `^\[[^][]*)]\s*(\w+):` and get Group 1

Comment: See my new edit :)

Comment: Look, you may get all details with a single regex - `^\[(\d+:\d+:\d+)]\s+(\d*)(\w+):\s+(.+)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/NgACex/1)).

Comment: To get just the ID: `m = re.search(r'^\[\d+:\d+:\d+]\s+(\w+):', c)` and then `if m: id_code = m.group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage from using [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

All the initial regex matching (after `c = row["content"]` and before `# get pid`) can be done with

```
match = re.search(r"^\[(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})]\s+(\w+):\s*(.*)", c)
if match:
  timestamp = match.group(1)
  id_code = match.group(2)
  only_content = match.group(3)
  if re.search(r"(?:Versuch(?:sleit(?:er)?)?|ersuchsleiter)", id_code):
    id_code = "Versuchsleiter"
```

Your timestamp will be `0:00:33`, only_content will hold `(content)` and id_code will contain `30091aA`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NgACex/2)

Comment: Thank you for your help but this give me the following error

Comment: @Shuzo I do not know how you are using my code in yours, but you have a typo somewhere as you see my code works. It also shows how to extract ID.

Comment: I get several error codes back like

(TypeError: not enough arguments for format string)

or

(line 590, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help but this gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/.../.../....py", line 80, in <module>
    insert_or_update(engine, d, "sql table")

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```